# Why esp8266 wifi connection automatically disconnecting while switch on the AC appliance?

Tags: android, arduino-uno, esp8266, home-automation

I am new for `esp8266` device. Actually I'm interfacing esp8266 wifi device with **Arduino** for wifi and **Android** based home automation. But when I switch on the light that time, wifi connection automatically disconnecting.

Why it's happening? And what is the reason behind that?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess switching on the AC device either causes electrical interference (the spark on the relay can be quite bad) which breaks your WIFI signal, or interrupts the power supply to the ESP8266, which can cause WIFI to fail.

But you really really really need to be more descriptive if you want a helpful answer :)

- What is your exact setup, what is connected to what, and how, how are your power supplies organized, etc.
- I wouldn't rule out a software error either, so can you give some details on your software setup also?
- Be specific on the details on the failure, what does 'wifi connection automatically disconnecting' mean, exactly? Log files help.

Comment: 1.   Arduino has connected with ESP8266  and it is powered 5v from 8051 board and also i'm giving power to relay12v from 8051 board and ESP8266 3.3v from arduino board                                                           2.   I'll send you the software                                                                  3.   Actually i'm operating the same system without load at relay, that time it is working properly, means frequently i could switch on and off  the relay without any wifi connection failure. But not working  properly with load

Comment: So with and without load, do you mean with and without an AC device connected? It works without? Is the device a lamp? Is it a glow bulb or a CF bulb or a LED bulb? Can you try with another 'load'? And can you double check it works without load? So far I'm still thinking EM interference, mayby from the relay sparking, or mayby from the device you're turning on. If you turn the device on with a normal switch, do you also lose connection?

Comment: Hello sir i checked with 12 volt dac bulb and 230v 60watts ac bulb. while switch on the relay with load i lose the wifi connection. when i remove the load from relay that time relay switch on and off properly and wifi connection also available

Comment: Hmm, that is odd, but at least a lot more specific :)
The only thing I can think of is that the relay sparks, and creates so much EM interference that it throws the WIFI off, but I wouldn't say that's a common issue. Turning on a AC device with a manual switch doesn't cause the same issue? Is this on a breadboard, are there any ways to change your layout, move the relay further from the ESP? To be honest I'm out of ideas on how to solve it :)

Comment: Oh, and you could also try http://electronics.stackexchange.com, if it's EM interference, they might be better suited to find an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of issues with EMI and RFI when it comes to media or commands with automation and distributed AV.  In fact there is still one area of my house approx. 2sqft that simply goes not get any wifi and will kill hdmi data.  i have done certain things to adapt to it while I figure out the issue but if it was an EMI or RFI issue you would be able to hear it with a tone generator used to sniff wires.  If it is an EMI issue it could possibly be a bad ground connection and i am assuming that is what my issue is however it is an extremely high voltage and current wiring (not romex it carries the power to the hvac and steam room unit) and will have to wait to shut down all the power to the house and possibly get an electrician over here also to make sure I don't burn the house down or electrocute myself.  Being zapped isn't that bad if the breaker trips but this particular one is a bit worrisome.